# Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder shows complete blank screen on build

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, electron-builder

When I build my electron app with [this plugin](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder), all I get when installing the package is a blank, white, screen. I've configured the window to open dev tools in the built version, but when I look at the inspect menu, the only content on the page are the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags, and there are no errors; the console is completely empty:

[image: blank screen]

**Elements:**
[image: elements]

**Console:**
[image: console]

I've looked just about everywhere online, but none of the solutions there worked.

I have tried changing the router mode from history to hash and also running `vue invoke electron-builder`, but they didn't help.

From what I can tell, this is failing:

```
win.loadURL('app://index.html')
```

because the path is incorrect. But I don't know if that's the case or if it's something else, since there are no errors reported.

Here's my `background.js` file:

```
'use strict'

import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import { createProtocol } from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
import installExtension, { VUEJS_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer'

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win

// Scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  { scheme: 'app', privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } }
])

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1500,
    height: 845,
    webPreferences: {
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true
    }
  })


  win.removeMenu()
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    // if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools();
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL('app://index.html')
  }
  win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    win.show();
  })

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
    // Install Vue Devtools
    try {
      await installExtension(VUEJS_DEVTOOLS)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Vue Devtools failed to install:', e.toString())
    }
  }
  createWindow()
})



// Exit cleanly on request from parent process in development mode.
if (isDevelopment) {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    process.on('message', (data) => {
      if (data === 'graceful-exit') {
        app.quit()
      }
    })
  } else {
    process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
      app.quit()
    })
  }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after more Googling, I stumbled upon [this site](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/53990214.shtml) which suggested to do this:

Replace your default `win.loadURL()` (which might look like this:

```
win.loadURL(formatUrl({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');,
      protocol: 'file',
      slashes: true
    }))
```

or it could be different; it doesn't matter), with this:

```
win.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
```

Basically, the difference is that this just removes the `formatUrl` which seems to screw things up.

I replaced mine, which was:

```
win.loadURL("app://./index.html");
```

with this, and it works fine now.

Also make sure you don't delete `createProtocol('app')` if that is there too, (it was a few lines above `win.loadUrl()`), because you could break your app :).

Answer (score 1):

I found that solution is to change router mode from "history" to "hash". So in router config set:

> mode: process.env.IS_ELECTRON ? 'hash' : 'history',

Problem solution [source](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/commonIssues.html#blank-screen-on-builds-but-works-fine-on-serve)

Comment: Yes, I've tried this, as I specified in the question. It's a common solution, but it didn't work in my case

Answer (score 0):

if you are using vue-router, make sure to set it on "hash mode".

source: **https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/commonIssues.html**